# how to let two ViewControllers use one NSObject

Tags: iphone, ios, viewcontroller, nsobject

If you have one NSObject that you want two ViewControllers to be able to use, how do you know which ViewController is calling it so when you pass what ever data you are computing back, you pass it back to the correct ViewController.

Comment: to be honest. I have no idea what you're asking here. Maybe you can rephrase the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the returned data to change based on the caller, create a method in the object you are retrieving data from rather than directly accessing a property.

In your `NSObject`, you could have a method that follows this format (my example is returning a string):

```
- (NSString *)getDataFor:(NSInteger)callingController {

    NSString *outputString = nil;

    if (callingController == 1) {
        // set value of output string for controller 1
    } else if (callingController == 2) {
        // set value of output string for controller 2
    }

    return outputString;

}
```

Then, from your view controller, you just call the method with the appropriate identifier as input.

Comment: AHH HA! thats exactly what I am thinking of... now that you mention it ahaha, thank you very much.

Comment: Uh, why not just have two methods, one "getTheDataThatVC1Wants", and the other "getTheDataThatVC2Wants"?